# Oauth redirects to localhost when hosted on server

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I hope you can help.

This script works locally for Google Analytics Auth, but when I put it on my server & run it with python3 xxx.py and go to the auth URL it redirects to localhost, which fails because it's on the server.

Does anyone have any idea why?

or even a nice Python example of connecting to Google Analytics. I've researched a lot & I couldn't get the examples I've seen working.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('./client_secret.json', SCOPES)
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not working because you followed an example for authenticating with an installed application

> InstalledAppFlow

Will open the authorization web browser window on the machine its running on.   if you intend to host this on a website to allow users to access their google analytics data you will need to use web browser credentials and the code for authenticating with a web browser.

## Oauth2 web application

The only sample i have been able to find for that is for the YouTube api you will need to alter it for Google anltyics

```
@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
  # Create a flow instance to manage the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Grant Flow
  # steps.
  flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
  flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)
  authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
      # This parameter enables offline access which gives your application
      # both an access and refresh token.
      access_type='offline',
      # This parameter enables incremental auth.
      include_granted_scopes='true')

  # Store the state in the session so that the callback can verify that
  # the authorization server response.
  flask.session['state'] = state

  return flask.redirect(authorization_url)
```

The full sample can be found [here](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/quickstart_web.py)

## service account.

If you will only be accessing your own data and not the data owned by others then you should consider using a service account.   [Hello Analytics Reporting API v4; Python quickstart for service accounts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py)

this uses

```
 credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
  KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)
```